# How to make svg take 100% of the screen no matter the screen size

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a website where there is an SVG. In order to make it look like the designer wanted I had to scale it (`transform: scale()`). To cover the part which goes beyond the width of the viewport, I used `overflow-x: hidden` on the body tag. It works perfectly for all screens. But on touchscreen devices, it doesn't work and `<html>` is wider than `<body>` (you can scroll right with `overflow-x: hidden` on the body). I tried to play with viewBox property, but I can't quite understand how it works.

Also, I tried to apply `width` and `max-width` properties to the SVG and path - no result.

The SVG code:

```html
        <svg class='service-line' id="move_path" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 0 1920 399" fill="none" version="1.1">
            <path id="move_path"  d="m0 192c0 0 156.5-61.7 235.7-90.1 57.1-20.5 114.2-41.7 172.6-58.1 33.9-9.5 67.7-22.7 102.9-23.2 34.9-0.5 71.7 4.2 102.9 19.9 32.9 16.6 63.3 42.6 81.3 74.7 19.6 34.9 27.3 78 23.2 117.8-3.2 31.9-17.4 63.5-37.1 88.8-19.4 25-47.3 43.4-75.8 57.2-23.7 11.5-50 19.9-76.3 19.9-30.9 0-62.2-9-89.6-23.2-25.8-13.4-49.8-32.6-66.4-56.4-19.2-27.6-32.8-61.1-34.9-94.6-2.4-38.6 6.6-79.8 26.6-112.9 20.8-34.6 54.7-62.6 91.3-79.7 36-16.8 78.4-13.2 117.8-18.3 33.1-4.2 66.3-7.7 99.6-10 30.4-2.1 60.8-3.4 91.3-3.3 28.8 0 57.6 1.7 86.3 3.3 29.4 1.7 58.8 2.7 88 6.6C965.5 14.2 992.1 17.4 1017 26c25.3 8.7 51.1 19.1 71.8 36.1 22.2 18.2 42.5 41.3 53.1 68 15 37.7 19.8 81.4 11.6 121.2-6.9 34-26.2 65.9-49.8 91.3-17.9 19.4-41.2 35.1-66.4 43.2-38 12.1-80.6 13.9-119.5 5-26.3-6-50.9-20.5-71.2-38.3-25-22-47.6-49.7-58.3-81.2-11.7-34.6-11.7-74-3.3-109.5 7.2-30.6 23.8-59.6 44.8-83 18.8-21 40-34.1 69.7-48.1 17.6-8.3 78.6-17.2 118.3-20.5 43.2-3.6 78.2-8.1 117.4-9.4 34.8-1.1 69.7 0.3 104.6 1.7 34.3 1.4 68.7 2.9 102.9 6.6C1379 13 1416.3 14.6 1451 26c31.8 10.4 66.5 21.5 89.2 46 33.7 36.4 56.1 87.4 57.8 137 1.4 40.6-14.9 83-39.5 115.3-23.9 31.3-60.1 55.4-97.9 66.4-36.1 10.5-77.2 8.8-112.9-3.3-34.9-11.9-66.2-36.2-89.6-64.7-18.5-22.6-31.8-50.8-36.5-79.7-5.9-36.2-2.3-75.6 11.6-109.5 11.3-27.6 32.6-51.1 55.6-70.1 18.1-15 39.6-26.7 62.3-32.8C1383.2 21.8 1417.9 22 1451 26c38.8 4.6 75.2 21 112.4 32.8 55.2 17.5 109.8 36.9 164.3 56.4 41.7 15 83.3 30.3 124.5 46.6C1875 170.8 1920 190 1920 190" >
            </path>
        </svg>
```

How can I work around that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to set `fill="red"` for example instead of `fill="none"`otherwise it won't show you anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the correct viewBox setting where your SVG takes up 100% of the browser window width.
This can be seen using the JS getBBox() method.
It is convenient to use `style = "border: 1px solid red;"` in SVG header. Red border shows the borders of the SVG canvas

```html
<svg class='service-line' id="move_path" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 0 1920 399" fill="none" version="1.1" style="border:1px solid red">
            <path  id="move" id="move_path"  stroke="black"  d="m0 192c0 0 156.5-61.7 235.7-90.1 57.1-20.5 114.2-41.7 172.6-58.1 33.9-9.5 67.7-22.7 102.9-23.2 34.9-0.5 71.7 4.2 102.9 19.9 32.9 16.6 63.3 42.6 81.3 74.7 19.6 34.9 27.3 78 23.2 117.8-3.2 31.9-17.4 63.5-37.1 88.8-19.4 25-47.3 43.4-75.8 57.2-23.7 11.5-50 19.9-76.3 19.9-30.9 0-62.2-9-89.6-23.2-25.8-13.4-49.8-32.6-66.4-56.4-19.2-27.6-32.8-61.1-34.9-94.6-2.4-38.6 6.6-79.8 26.6-112.9 20.8-34.6 54.7-62.6 91.3-79.7 36-16.8 78.4-13.2 117.8-18.3 33.1-4.2 66.3-7.7 99.6-10 30.4-2.1 60.8-3.4 91.3-3.3 28.8 0 57.6 1.7 86.3 3.3 29.4 1.7 58.8 2.7 88 6.6C965.5 14.2 992.1 17.4 1017 26c25.3 8.7 51.1 19.1 71.8 36.1 22.2 18.2 42.5 41.3 53.1 68 15 37.7 19.8 81.4 11.6 121.2-6.9 34-26.2 65.9-49.8 91.3-17.9 19.4-41.2 35.1-66.4 43.2-38 12.1-80.6 13.9-119.5 5-26.3-6-50.9-20.5-71.2-38.3-25-22-47.6-49.7-58.3-81.2-11.7-34.6-11.7-74-3.3-109.5 7.2-30.6 23.8-59.6 44.8-83 18.8-21 40-34.1 69.7-48.1 17.6-8.3 78.6-17.2 118.3-20.5 43.2-3.6 78.2-8.1 117.4-9.4 34.8-1.1 69.7 0.3 104.6 1.7 34.3 1.4 68.7 2.9 102.9 6.6C1379 13 1416.3 14.6 1451 26c31.8 10.4 66.5 21.5 89.2 46 33.7 36.4 56.1 87.4 57.8 137 1.4 40.6-14.9 83-39.5 115.3-23.9 31.3-60.1 55.4-97.9 66.4-36.1 10.5-77.2 8.8-112.9-3.3-34.9-11.9-66.2-36.2-89.6-64.7-18.5-22.6-31.8-50.8-36.5-79.7-5.9-36.2-2.3-75.6 11.6-109.5 11.3-27.6 32.6-51.1 55.6-70.1 18.1-15 39.6-26.7 62.3-32.8C1383.2 21.8 1417.9 22 1451 26c38.8 4.6 75.2 21 112.4 32.8 55.2 17.5 109.8 36.9 164.3 56.4 41.7 15 83.3 30.3 124.5 46.6C1875 170.8 1920 190 1920 190" >
   </path>
</svg> 
<script>
    let bb = move.getBBox();
        console.log(bb);
</script>
```

When applied, let's say `transform =" scale (1.1) "` the image is enlarged and shifted to the right and down

There are three ways to put it back in place:

1. Increase the `width` and `height` of the `viewBox` exactly as many times as the image was enlarged using `scale`  In other words, you need to multiply by 1.1 (scale factor (1.1))

instead of `viewBox = "0 0 1920 399"` set `viewBox = "0 0 2012 438.9"`

```css
.container {
width:100vw;
height:100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg class='service-line' id="move_path" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 0 2012 438.9" fill="none" version="1.1" style="border:1px solid red">
            <path  id="move" id="move_path" transform="scale(1.1 1.1)" stroke="black"  d="m0 192c0 0 156.5-61.7 235.7-90.1 57.1-20.5 114.2-41.7 172.6-58.1 33.9-9.5 67.7-22.7 102.9-23.2 34.9-0.5 71.7 4.2 102.9 19.9 32.9 16.6 63.3 42.6 81.3 74.7 19.6 34.9 27.3 78 23.2 117.8-3.2 31.9-17.4 63.5-37.1 88.8-19.4 25-47.3 43.4-75.8 57.2-23.7 11.5-50 19.9-76.3 19.9-30.9 0-62.2-9-89.6-23.2-25.8-13.4-49.8-32.6-66.4-56.4-19.2-27.6-32.8-61.1-34.9-94.6-2.4-38.6 6.6-79.8 26.6-112.9 20.8-34.6 54.7-62.6 91.3-79.7 36-16.8 78.4-13.2 117.8-18.3 33.1-4.2 66.3-7.7 99.6-10 30.4-2.1 60.8-3.4 91.3-3.3 28.8 0 57.6 1.7 86.3 3.3 29.4 1.7 58.8 2.7 88 6.6C965.5 14.2 992.1 17.4 1017 26c25.3 8.7 51.1 19.1 71.8 36.1 22.2 18.2 42.5 41.3 53.1 68 15 37.7 19.8 81.4 11.6 121.2-6.9 34-26.2 65.9-49.8 91.3-17.9 19.4-41.2 35.1-66.4 43.2-38 12.1-80.6 13.9-119.5 5-26.3-6-50.9-20.5-71.2-38.3-25-22-47.6-49.7-58.3-81.2-11.7-34.6-11.7-74-3.3-109.5 7.2-30.6 23.8-59.6 44.8-83 18.8-21 40-34.1 69.7-48.1 17.6-8.3 78.6-17.2 118.3-20.5 43.2-3.6 78.2-8.1 117.4-9.4 34.8-1.1 69.7 0.3 104.6 1.7 34.3 1.4 68.7 2.9 102.9 6.6C1379 13 1416.3 14.6 1451 26c31.8 10.4 66.5 21.5 89.2 46 33.7 36.4 56.1 87.4 57.8 137 1.4 40.6-14.9 83-39.5 115.3-23.9 31.3-60.1 55.4-97.9 66.4-36.1 10.5-77.2 8.8-112.9-3.3-34.9-11.9-66.2-36.2-89.6-64.7-18.5-22.6-31.8-50.8-36.5-79.7-5.9-36.2-2.3-75.6 11.6-109.5 11.3-27.6 32.6-51.1 55.6-70.1 18.1-15 39.6-26.7 62.3-32.8C1383.2 21.8 1417.9 22 1451 26c38.8 4.6 75.2 21 112.4 32.8 55.2 17.5 109.8 36.9 164.3 56.4 41.7 15 83.3 30.3 124.5 46.6C1875 170.8 1920 190 1920 190" >
            </path>
        </svg> 
</div>
```

2. Use translate (x, y) with negative values

However, part of the image will be cropped.

3. Use the first two viewBox attributes to move the image.
   Positive values will shift the image back to the left and up.
   For example `viewBox = "10 10 1920 399"`

*It is preferable to use the first method with proportional increase in the viewBox, since it does not require additional settings*

Answer (score 1):

First: You need to set `fill="red"` for example instead of `fill="none"`otherwise it won't show you anything.

Set 100vw (viewport width) as : `svg{ min-width: 100vw !important; width: 100vw !important; }`

But this will make the svg the equal size of the screen. So if you set a `margin-left: 200px` It will create an overflow-x so make sure to have the svg totaly stick to the left:0 of your screen

```css
body{
  margin:0;
}

svg{
  min-width: 100vw !important;
  width: 100vw !important;
}
```

```html
<svg class='service-line' id="move_path" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 0 1920 399" fill="red" version="1.1">
            <path id="move_path"  d="m0 192c0 0 156.5-61.7 235.7-90.1 57.1-20.5 114.2-41.7 172.6-58.1 33.9-9.5 67.7-22.7 102.9-23.2 34.9-0.5 71.7 4.2 102.9 19.9 32.9 16.6 63.3 42.6 81.3 74.7 19.6 34.9 27.3 78 23.2 117.8-3.2 31.9-17.4 63.5-37.1 88.8-19.4 25-47.3 43.4-75.8 57.2-23.7 11.5-50 19.9-76.3 19.9-30.9 0-62.2-9-89.6-23.2-25.8-13.4-49.8-32.6-66.4-56.4-19.2-27.6-32.8-61.1-34.9-94.6-2.4-38.6 6.6-79.8 26.6-112.9 20.8-34.6 54.7-62.6 91.3-79.7 36-16.8 78.4-13.2 117.8-18.3 33.1-4.2 66.3-7.7 99.6-10 30.4-2.1 60.8-3.4 91.3-3.3 28.8 0 57.6 1.7 86.3 3.3 29.4 1.7 58.8 2.7 88 6.6C965.5 14.2 992.1 17.4 1017 26c25.3 8.7 51.1 19.1 71.8 36.1 22.2 18.2 42.5 41.3 53.1 68 15 37.7 19.8 81.4 11.6 121.2-6.9 34-26.2 65.9-49.8 91.3-17.9 19.4-41.2 35.1-66.4 43.2-38 12.1-80.6 13.9-119.5 5-26.3-6-50.9-20.5-71.2-38.3-25-22-47.6-49.7-58.3-81.2-11.7-34.6-11.7-74-3.3-109.5 7.2-30.6 23.8-59.6 44.8-83 18.8-21 40-34.1 69.7-48.1 17.6-8.3 78.6-17.2 118.3-20.5 43.2-3.6 78.2-8.1 117.4-9.4 34.8-1.1 69.7 0.3 104.6 1.7 34.3 1.4 68.7 2.9 102.9 6.6C1379 13 1416.3 14.6 1451 26c31.8 10.4 66.5 21.5 89.2 46 33.7 36.4 56.1 87.4 57.8 137 1.4 40.6-14.9 83-39.5 115.3-23.9 31.3-60.1 55.4-97.9 66.4-36.1 10.5-77.2 8.8-112.9-3.3-34.9-11.9-66.2-36.2-89.6-64.7-18.5-22.6-31.8-50.8-36.5-79.7-5.9-36.2-2.3-75.6 11.6-109.5 11.3-27.6 32.6-51.1 55.6-70.1 18.1-15 39.6-26.7 62.3-32.8C1383.2 21.8 1417.9 22 1451 26c38.8 4.6 75.2 21 112.4 32.8 55.2 17.5 109.8 36.9 164.3 56.4 41.7 15 83.3 30.3 124.5 46.6C1875 170.8 1920 190 1920 190" >
      </path>
  </svg>
```

Comment: @Vlad.Storozhenko Please have a look to the demo I set. You need to set `fill="red"` for example instead of `fill="none"`otherwise it won't show you anything